# Schema Change with Foreign Key Caused Metadata Locks

Tags: mysql, aurora

I ran this on an Aurora-MySQL (8.0.26 equivalent). I essentially have this schema change:

```
ALTER TABLE `t1`
      DROP FOREIGN KEY t1_ibfk_1,
      DROP FOREIGN KEY t1_ibfk_2,
      DROP INDEX `t1_IDX`,
      ADD INDEX `t1_IDX` (`t1_a_id`,`t1_b_id`),
      ADD CONSTRAINT `t1_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY t1_ibfk_1 (`t1_a_id`) REFERENCES `t2` (`a_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `t1_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY t1_ibfk_2 (`t1_b_id`) REFERENCES `t3` (`b_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

When I ran this on production, I saw metadata locks on a lot of tables. To the point that it seems to have locked the entire database. Even the "pmm user" (Percona monitoring tool) had metadata lock too. I don't understand why though. Also, table `t3` is heavily used by the app.

I just saw [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/286255/222807) and I have some questions:

1. The original index was a unique index and we wanted to make it a non-unique index. So I think dropping and re-adding the foreign key is the only way to do this, right?
2. Does it mean that if next time I have a schema change that creates a new table and it has a foreign key constraint, it will have a metadata lock on the parent table too?

EDIT: What if I run `set foreign_key_checks = 0;` before running the schema change? Would it prevent the metadata lock? The downside is that rows are not checked for consistency when foreign_key_checks is disabled. I probably need a SELECT query to check the data consistency after I finish running the schema change.